# Dependent Combobox in a Datasheet in Access?

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2007

I've created a dependent combobox as mentioned as this article. 
http://office.microsoft.com/en-au/access-help/basing-one-combo-box-on-another-HA001173058.aspx

However, the problem I'm having is that I'm trying to do this with a datasheet.  When I specify the criteria as another field, it'll look at the first row's value instead of the current row's value.  I'm willing to do this as a contiguous form as well, but don't know if that would help.

Comment: Could you clarify a little please, are you using combo boxes on a form and the showing the datasheet as part of a subform. Also what do you mean by specifying the criteria as another field?  Are you using a bound or unbound form?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unbound controls in a continuous form will only drive you insane. Consider modifying the underlying query to ensure that your combo is based on a bound column (field).

Comment: In my actual project it's a bound datasheet/continous form

Comment: @Brett If you refer to a control on the form as  `Forms!MyForm!Somecontrol` it will only ever be the record that has focus, which is where life gets difficult. I suggest you create a form that pops up for editing and just show bound information, not cascading combos.