# how do you update a specific row in Access subform?

Tags: ms-access, vba

So I have a form that contains a subform of items. Upon loading the form, each row has

1. Quantity
2. Product ID
3. Product Description

Product Description data should automatically be taken from the Product ID selected (combo box).

Currently, I have it as

```
 DESCRIPTION = [PRODUCT_id].[Column](3)
```

My problem is, this updates ALL the ROWS in the subform.

How do I target / reference a specific row in a subform?

thanks!

Comment: Continuous forms are great, but they have limitations, have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8731974/dependent-combobox-in-a-datasheet-in-access/8733045#8733045

Comment: Can you share more details, what table being used for the Form and which table for Sub form, what are Master/Child fields. Did you set Link Master Fields, Link Child Fields property of sub form ?